# Error al abrir ASP.NET antigua

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2010

Me han pasado un website antiguo hecho en Visual Studio 2010, necesito abrirlo para ver como es el funcionamiento interno.
Intento abrir el proyecto con VS2015 Profesional pero me da el siguiente error y no me lo abre.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradeceria si alguien me dice como puedo abrirlo ya que en el mundo ASP.NET apenas tengo experiencia.
Gracias

Comment: Has probado a abrirlo con visual10? yo tengo instaladas todas las versiones desde el 6.

Comment: @GDP hola, la verdad es que el VS2010 no lo tengo a mano, si no lo consigo abrir con el 10 mañana tendre que hacer las gestiones para poner el VS2010. gracias de todos modos.

Comment: Nunca he visto ese error, pero si que es verdad que tengo proyecto que tengo que abrir con la version que se crearon, sino petan. No vale migrarlos.

Comment: No creo que ese error tenga que ver con la versión de Visual Studio,sino mas bien con tu instalación del IIS. Lo primero que probaría es a abrir el visual studio en modo de administrador.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Este error se debe a que el Visual Studio intenta crear un directorio virtual en una unidad mapeada a la unidad `Z`, la cual puede que esté desconectada o no tengas permisos de escritura. También me parece que estás abriendo la solución desde una ruta externa a tu equipo.

Lo ideal es que abras la solución desde tu equipo para que no estés lidiando con fallos en la red, así como seguir las siguientes instrucciones para crear un directorio virtual local:

1. Una vez que tengas abierta tu solución, da clic en el menú <kbd>Project</kbd> y luego en <kbd>Properties</kbd>
2. Selecciona la pestaña <kbd>Web</kbd>, y `Project URL` asegúrate de tener una ruta hacia localhost:

   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
3. Da clic en el botón <kbd>Create Virtual Directory</kbd> y listo.

Con esto, estás creando un directorio virtual en tu IIS local, sin la necesidad de depender de una unidad externa a tu equipo y asegurando que la aplicación correrá directamente en tu `localhost`.

Comment: Perfecto!, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Intenta realizar lo siguiente:

1. Cierra el Visual Studio 2015
2. En la carpeta: C:\Users\USUARIO\Documents\IISExpress\config\
3. Busca el archivo: applicationhost.config
4. Renómbralo el archivo a: applicationhost_old.config
5. Intenta volver a cargar el proyecto de VS 2010 una vez más.